# mysql fetch record with valid date not 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i am trying to get all valid timestamp records using below query

```
SELECT * FROM table where mytimestamp IS NOT NULL
```

my query outputs records with value "0000-00-00 00:00:00"

that id do not want to occurs , what query should be firect in that case

Comment: I would replace the date `0000-00-00 00:00:00` with `null` in your table and prevent that it is inserted in the future

Comment: modify your column, change it to allowed null and change those invalid datetime to null

Comment: there's no php here, or "mysqli" to support the question or the db schema. If none of the answers given below didn't solve it, then you need to update your question with the code you're really using and the connection API used.

Answer (score 1):

My first question to you would be why are you storing the year zero, `0000-00-00 00:00:00` in your table in the first place?

In any case, you can add a condition to the `WHERE` clause to filter out this data if you really have it:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE mytimestamp IS NOT NULL AND
      mytimestamp > '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

This query is getting your desired output, Please try it -

```
SELECT * FROM table where mytimestamp != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table_name` 
where `column_name` IS NOT NULL AND `column_name` > '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```